# set value of dropdownlist inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that has a dropdownlist inside it. There is another separate dropdownlist outside the repeater. The user would select a value in this ddl, click a button, and the selected value  would be populated in all the ddl's inside the repeater that are blank. Note: the ddl's have text for selectedvalue (not ints).

Unfortunately my code is not working.

My markup:

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="AttendanceRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="AttendanceSqlDataSource" OnItemDataBound="AttendanceRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 50px"></td>
                            <td style="width: 300px">
                                <asp:Label ID="StudentNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STUDENT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 200px">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="AttendStatusDropDownList" runat="server"
                                    SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ATTENDANCE_STATUS") %>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="ABSENTE" Text="Absent Excused"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="ABSENTU" Text="Absent Unexcused"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="CIN" Text="Chk In No (Absent)"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="CIY" Text="Chk In Yes (Present)"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="NR" Text="Attend Not Reqd"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="PRESENT" Text="Present"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM005" Text="Time Missed 005 Min"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM010" Text="Time Missed 010 Min"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM015" Text="Time Missed 015 Min"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM030" Text="Time Missed 030 Min"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM045" Text="Time Missed 045 Min"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM060" Text="Time Missed 1hr"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM075" Text="Time Missed 1hr 15mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM090" Text="Time Missed 1hr 30mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM105" Text="Time Missed 1hr 45mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM120" Text="Time Missed 2hr"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM135" Text="Time Missed 2hr 15mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM150" Text="Time Missed 2hr 30mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM165" Text="Time Missed 2hr 45mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM180" Text="Time Missed 3hr"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM195" Text="Time Missed 3hr 15mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM210" Text="Time Missed 3hr 30mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM225" Text="Time Missed 3hr 45mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM240" Text="Time Missed 4hr"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM255" Text="Time Missed 4hr 15mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM310" Text="Time Missed 4hr 30mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="TM325" Text="Time Missed 4hr 45mi"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="WD" Text="Withdrawn"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AttendStatusValidator" runat="server"
                                    ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="AttendStatusDropDownList">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 200px">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="CommentsTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                    Text='<%# Eval("COMMENTS") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
<%--                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChangeCheckBox" runat="server" Visible="true" />--%>
                                <asp:Label ID="PeopleCodeIdLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PEOPLE_CODE_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="AcademicYearLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ACADEMIC_YEAR") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="AcademicTermLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ACADEMIC_TERM") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="AcademicSessionLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ACADEMIC_SESSION") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="EventIdLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("EVENT_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="EventSubTypeLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("EVENT_SUB_TYPE") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="SectionLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("SECTION") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="TranAttendanceIdLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("TranAttendanceId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code for the button: (Note the naming of the drop-downs. AttendanceStatusdropdownlist and AttendStatusAllDropDownList)

```
    protected void ApplyToAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string defaultStatus = AttendStatusAllDropDownList.SelectedValue;

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in AttendanceRepeater.Items)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("AttendanceStatusDropDownList");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddl.SelectedValue))
        {
            //set the ddl to the value selected from the other ddl
            ddl.SelectedValue = defaultStatus;

        }
    }
    //Save changes to all
    SaveButton_Click(null, null);
}
```

The values are not populating in the drop-downs inside the repeater. I have searched google but cannot find anything specific to what I'm attempting. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in your `FindControl` value and the `ID` of the DropDownList inside the Repeater.

Repeater:    `AttendStatusDropDownList`

FindControl: `AttendanceStatusDropDownList`

See the updated snippet below.

```
protected void ApplyToAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in AttendanceRepeater.Items)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("AttendStatusDropDownList");

        if (ddl != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl.SelectedValue))
        {
            ddl.SelectedValue = AttendStatusAllDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        }
    }    
}
```

ASPX page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="AttendStatusAllDropDownList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TM005" Text="Time Missed 005 Min"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TM010" Text="Time Missed 010 Min"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TM015" Text="Time Missed 015 Min"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TM030" Text="Time Missed 030 Min"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TM045" Text="Time Missed 045 Min"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="ApplyToAllButton_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Repeater ID="AttendanceRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AttendStatusDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TM005" Text="Time Missed 005 Min"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TM010" Text="Time Missed 010 Min"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TM015" Text="Time Missed 015 Min"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TM030" Text="Time Missed 030 Min"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="TM045" Text="Time Missed 045 Min"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I've gotta remember to check the little things! Thanks, but after I changed it, it's still not working. One thing to note: I need to make sure the attendstatusdropdownlist.selectedvalue is null, before I do the assignment. So I changed the code slightly.

Comment: I've added my test snippet. If I change `AttendStatusAllDropDownList` and press the button all the values inside the Repeater get updated that have no selection. So if your snippet does not work try my snippet on a different page and start adding things so you can see where the problem lies.

Comment: I found the problem. I have a required field validator on the dropdown inside the repeater. I tried removing it and the ddl's now get populated (it works). But the field is required. I think I'll try using a custom validator and see if it still works.

Comment: Just add `CausesValidation="false"` to the button that sets all the values.

Comment: I added  `CausesValidation="false"`and the field populates, but it doesn't visually populate, i.e. nothing shows up in the drop-down. I tried using a custom validator but intellisense doesn't recognize it in the code file and I get a compiler error if I try to reference it.